# How to set font size dynamically in a local report to fit textbox dimensions?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, report, rdlc

How can I set font size dynamically in textbox control on report so the content of textbox fit into its dimensions?
My idea was to decrease font size in loop based on value of next function:

```
Private Function IsContentsBiggerThanTextBox(ByVal textBox As TextBox) As Boolean
    Dim size As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox.Text, textBox.Font)
    Return ((size.Width > textBox.Width)  OR (size.Height > textBox.Height))
End Function
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass reference of report textbox to function.

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts to find code that works in local rdlc reports, I finally managed to write functions that dynamically adjust font size in textbox control, depending on the size of text in it. The idea is to measure text size in textbox control with fixed dimensions, and if we find that text height is higher than height of the textbox control, we reduce size of the font until text fits in control.

First you have to add reference to System.Drawing in Report Properties.

All code in rdlc report has to be written in vb.net. In Code field of report properties add these functions:

```
'1cm = 37.79527559055 pixels
Const cmToPx as Single = 37.79527559055F

Public Function setMaxFont(Text as string, boxWidth as Single, boxHeight as 
Single, FontMax as Integer, FontMin as Integer) as String
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = FontMax to FontMin Step -1
        If IsTextSmaller(Text, i, boxWidth, boxHeight) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    return i & "pt"
End Function


Private Function IsTextSmaller(Text as String, fontValue as Integer, boxWidth as Single, boxHeight as Single) as Boolean
    Dim stringFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", fontValue) 
    Dim stringSize As New System.Drawing.SizeF
    Dim boxSize as New System.Drawing.SizeF(boxWidth * cmToPx, boxHeight * cmToPx * 10) 'we set box height bigger than textbox that we check
    Dim bitmap as System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1)
    Dim g As  System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
    g.PageUnit = System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel
    stringSize = g.MeasureString(Text, stringFont, boxSize)
    bitmap = Nothing
    return stringSize.Height < (boxHeight * cmToPx)
End Function
```

Select textbox control whose font size you want to change dynamically and in FontSize property add code below:

```
= Code.SetMaxFont(TextBox.Value, WidthOfTextBox, HeightOfTextBox, MaxFontSize, MinFontSize)
```

Width and height of textbox has to be entered in centimeters. CanGrow and CanShrink properties of textbox must be set to False.

Comment: You can also reuse code by simply handing the fontName in as a variable.